# Data dictionary mgmt - dynamically fetching list of tables in DB

Tags: java, database, data-dictionary

I've recently faced a task to create an application for data dictionary managing (no matter if it is desktop or web app) based on DB.

The main question is how to fetch list of tables dynamically (eg. admin is adding new dictionaries at the DB level, users are only viewing and filling in missing values) easily? It cannot be a static mapping since the configuration/re-deployment is not taken into account.

Do you think that JavaFX/J2EE is sufficient or do you know some other platform which will allow to do that more easily?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

these info is stored in system tables. it depends on which db you use

example for oracle

SELECT  table_name  FROM dba_tables

Comment: Yeah, but the dictionary in my case is a business dictionary, eg. products, services etc., not the system dictionary (like in Oracle). To specify - there are simply tables with data, but I need to get list of that tables dynamically, not by static binding (like in Hibernate).